# How to fix 'Bus Error' in python code to receive a signal?

Tags: python, macos, signals

I created a python code following [this description](https://stackabuse.com/handling-unix-signals-in-python/):

```
import os
import time
import signal

def receiveSignal(signalNumber, frame):
    print('Received:', signalNumber)
    return

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receiveSignal)

# output current process id
print('My PID is:', os.getpid())

# wait in an endless loop for signals
while True:
    print('Waiting...')
    time.sleep(3)
```

which runs fine. But when I try to send a `SIGUSR1` signal from another terminal, e.g. :

```
kill -10 55947
```

the python code fails as follows:

```
My PID is: 55947
Waiting...
Waiting...
Bus error: 10
```

The code is running on MacOS 10.13.6, and I tried using python 2.7.12 and python 3.6.2. In both cases I get that `Bus Error`.

Is there a way to fix that? Maybe this is a mac issue? I expect the running code to execute the method `receiveSignal`, but otherwise stay in the `shile` loop.

Comment: Try `kill -SIGUSR1 <pid>` instead of the `kill -10 <pid>` :-P. If you use the string presentation of the signal, then you do not make a mistake with an incorrect signal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is, in MacOS, the `SIGNAL 10` means `SIGBUS`.

See the signal list https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html

See the signal details,

```
     1     SIGHUP       terminate process    terminal line hangup
     2     SIGINT       terminate process    interrupt program
     3     SIGQUIT      create core image    quit program
     4     SIGILL       create core image    illegal instruction
     5     SIGTRAP      create core image    trace trap
     6     SIGABRT      create core image    abort program (formerly SIGIOT)
     7     SIGEMT       create core image    emulate instruction executed
     8     SIGFPE       create core image    floating-point exception
     9     SIGKILL      terminate process    kill program
     10    SIGBUS       create core image    bus error
     ...
     ...
     30    SIGUSR1      terminate process    User defined signal 1
     31    SIGUSR2      terminate process    User defined signal 2
```

Hence, the error.

Try sending `SIGNAL 30`, and see :)